# ¿Como trabajar las bitácoras en una base de datos?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Tengo una tabla llamada `bitacoras`:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."bitacoras" (
"id" int4 DEFAULT nextval('bitacoras_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
"cod_op" varchar(255) COLLATE "default" NOT NULL,
"descripcion_op" varchar(255) COLLATE "default" NOT NULL,
"id_sesiones" int4 NOT NULL,
"acceso" bool NOT NULL,
"fecha_op" date NOT NULL,
"hora_op" timestamptz(0) NOT NULL,
"valor_anterior" varchar(255) COLLATE "default" NOT NULL,
"valor_nuevo" varchar(255) COLLATE "default" NOT NULL,
"created_at" timestamp(0),
"updated_at" timestamp(0)
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE)
;
```

Cuando el usuario loguea envió el `id` del `user` a esta tabla.

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."sesiones" (
"id" int4 DEFAULT nextval('sesiones_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
"id_users" int4 NOT NULL,
"fecha" date NOT NULL,
"created_at" timestamp(0),
"updated_at" timestamp(0)
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE)
;
```

En la tabla `bitacoras` registro los distintos movimiento que realizan los usuarios con `triggers`. De la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Bitacora()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN 
     INSERT INTO bitacora (cod_op, descripcion_op, nom_usu, acceso, fecha_op, hora_op, valor_old, valor_new) 
     VALUES('DEL','Elimina Datos de ' || upper(TG_TABLE_NAME),(SELECT MAX(id) FROM sesiones), true, current_date, current_time, OLD, NULL);
     RETURN OLD;
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    INSERT INTO bitacora (cod_op, descripcion_op, nom_usu, acceso, fecha_op, hora_op, valor_old, valor_new)
     VALUES('UPD','Actualiza Datos de ' || upper(TG_TABLE_NAME),(SELECT MAX(id) FROM sesiones), true, current_date, current_time, OLD, NEW);
     RETURN NEW;
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
     INSERT INTO bitacora (cod_op, descripcion_op, nom_usu, acceso, fecha_op, hora_op, valor_old, valor_new)
     VALUES('INS','Inserta Datos de ' || upper(TG_TABLE_NAME),(SELECT MAX(id) FROM sesiones), true, current_date, current_time, NULL, NEW);
     RETURN NEW;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION Bitacora()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Todo funciona perfecto. Solo tengo un problema, sucede que cuando logueo con un usuario, llamemoslo `usuario1`, y hago cualquier movimiento me lo registra bien pero si a su vez otro usuario en la red, llamemoslo `usuario2`, también loguea, este otro registra su `id` como el ultimo en haber iniciado, entonces el `usuario1` realiza cualquier movimiento y la `base de datos` obtiene el ultimo `id` logueado que en este caso es el `id` del `usuario2`.

¿Como podría solucionar este problema? o ¿Lo estoy trabajando de manera equivocada?

Comment: Hola Pablo, creo que el problema que tienes es aquí: (SELECT MAX(id) FROM inicio_de_sesion) que para seleccionar el id del usuario siempre seleccionas el último inicio de sesión.

Comment: @FernandoForcén si pero como lo solucionaría?

Comment: Pues, o al select max le pones un `where user_id = algo`y/o los autenticas a cada uno con crdenciales separadas. Puedes usar info de la tabla `pg_stat_activity` para ver los usuarios activos. Aca puede haber un registro por cada sesión creada (a tener en cuenta si se una un pool de conexiones)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en la insert del trigger estás usando siempre esta select `(SELECT MAX(id) FROM inicio_de_sesion)` que provoca que siempre añadas la información del ultimo usuario que ha iniciado la sesión.

Para resolver esto tendrías que usar información relativa a la sesión de cada usuario. Se me ocurren dos opciones, o que cada usuario entre con su propio usuario y contraseña a la base de datos... o que (si estás en SQLServer) uses `CONTEXT_INFO`. Te dejo un enlace a la página de Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189252.aspx

Básicamente se trata de almacenar información en la sesión del usuario y usarla en la insert en lugar de utilizar la SELECT.

Explora estas posibilidades a ver si te sirven.

Comment: yo utilizo PostgreSql

Comment: PostgreSql no soporta variables de sesión en el servidor, pero he visto esto que lo mismo puede darte alguna idea: http://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks_II#Any_other_session_variables